# Custom Border at the Bottom

Tags: html, css

I want to make a div with a custom border at the bottom. The div should look like that:

[image]

So there should be an arrow at the bottom left, while the right part (just the line) should expand dynamically, according to the width.

I took the [example from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image) and tried to modify it.

CSS:

```
#borderimg1 {
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  padding: 15px;
  -webkit-border-image: url(arrow.png) 30 round;
  /* Safari 3.1-5 */
  -o-border-image: url(arrow.png) 30 round;
  /* Opera 11-12.1 */
  border-image: url(arrow.png) 30 round;
}

#borderimg2 {
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  padding: 15px;
  -webkit-border-image: url(arrow.png) 30 stretch;
  /* Safari 3.1-5 */
  -o-border-image: url(arrow.png) 30 stretch;
  /* Opera 11-12.1 */
  border-image: url(arrow.png) 30 stretch;
}
```

HTML:

```
 The border-image property specifies an image to be used as the border around an element:</p>
    <p id="borderimg1">Here, the middle sections of the image are repeated to create the border.</p>
    <p id="borderimg2">Here, the middle sections of the image are stretched to create the border.</p>
```

But it just doesn't show me any border.

*Note: arrow.png is an image I have locally on my machine.*

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
// le div
<div class='hello'>Hi there</div>

// le css
.hello {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  overflow: display;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.hello::after {
  content: '';
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background: url(http://www.charbase.com/images/glyph/11021);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px;
  background-position: 10px 0px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/duhaime/pen/yMExKP

Comment: Is it possible, to make it more dynamically, so that I don't have to specify `top: 48px;`?

Comment: Ok, as @takendarkk already mentioned, the arrow moves when I put some content into the div.

Comment: @user1170330 ah, just add `left: 0px` to the `::after` styles (I updated my response)